# How to take x most frequent location by hour with pyspark?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, data-analysis

I have a spark dataframe with hour of day, locationID and frequency.
Frequency is how many times a locationID appears in that hour of day.

```
+----+----------+---------+
|hour|locationID|frequency|
+----+----------+---------+
| 0  |     1    |    20   |
| 0  |     2    |    11   |   
| 0  |     9    |     6   |
| 1  |     3    |    32   |
| 1  |     1    |    22   |
| 1  |     5    |     4   |
```

I want to take the 2 most frequent locationID per hour.

Comment: Many ways to do it, for example you can use DF api order by and top, You can create a view from the DF and run sql query which uses order by and Limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with a `row_number` window function. The window groups by `hour` and orders the `frequency` in descending order. Thereafter, filter for the top 2 rows.

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number,desc
w = Window.partitionBy(df.hour).orderBy(df.frequency.desc())
rnum_df = df.withColumn('rnum',row_number().over(w))
rnum_df.filter(rnum_df.rnum <= 2).show()
```